# OpenIdConnectSecurityKeyProvider.RetrieveMetaData Exception - Unable to retrieve document from :'System.String'

Tags: openid-connect, owin, adal, msal.js

This has been working for 3+ years. This morning everything is broken.

My SPA uses a C# Web API on the backend and MSAL.js on the front end. Users Auth via O365 to get a Bearer Token, all web requests pass the token to the API backend. After spending most the morning reacquainting myself with this tech stack I think I can ask a semi intelligent question.

The OpenIdConnectSecurityKeyProvider.RetrieveMetaData method is throwing a fatal exception when trying to retrieve the configuration

`OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = ConfigManager.GetConfigurationAsync().Result;`

At first I was getting this error.

*"InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden]'"*

After upgrading several Microsoft.IdentityModel packages and Microsoft.Owin packages the exception being thrown is.

*IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'. HttpResponseMessage: 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage',*

Any ideas how to continue to debug this would very helpful.

Comment: The error you are getting is due to your application's configuration is not able to retrieve the OIDC metadata properly. Did you update your application configuration recently? Could you share the configurations you are setting while configuring the application? It should have correct Instance","Domain","TenantId","ClientId' to retrieve the metadata.

Comment: Are you using ADAL?

Comment: +1 on the same issue, I have an application which was working fine for 2+ years where I had implemented Microsoft Azure Authentication using owin libraries and suddenly stopped working with the "Unable to retrieve document from :'System.String'" message, till now i haven't found a solution :-(

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this works for you or not, but for me adding this line in ***startup.cs*** worked:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

This stems from the article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/enable-support-tls-environment?tabs=azure-monitor

So I think there is a way to switch the TLS Method by default in the OS level but for the time being the above code change worked.

Answer (score 0):

MS has shut off TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and 3DES encryption for Azure AD and ultimately GraphAPI. To uncover the actual error I had to enable PII (Personally Identifiable Information). Bascially the PII is/was the API key which also included the full stack error from Azure AD. You can enable this in your startup.cs or where ever you initialize the IAppBuilder interface. Here's the announcement from MS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/enable-support-tls-environment?tabs=azure-monitor#enable-tls-12-on-client-or-server-operating-systems-

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MERP.Startup))]
namespace MERP
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; //Important for debugging
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

After getting the actual error, bascially something to the effect of TLS Version not supported. I had to enable TLS 1.2 using powershell scripts. Here's a MS article with PS Scripts to enable TLS 1.2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-tls-enforcement

Enable TLS 1.2 PS Scripts for ease of access

```
If (-Not (Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319'))
{
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319' -Force | Out-Null
}
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SystemDefaultTlsVersions' -Value '1' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

If (-Not (Test-Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319'))
{
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319' -Force | Out-Null
}
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SystemDefaultTlsVersions' -Value '1' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

If (-Not (Test-Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server'))
{
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -Force | Out-Null
}
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -Name 'Enabled' -Value '1' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server' -Name 'DisabledByDefault' -Value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

If (-Not (Test-Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client'))
{
    New-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -Force | Out-Null
}
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -Name 'Enabled' -Value '1' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client' -Name 'DisabledByDefault' -Value '0' -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force | Out-Null

Write-Host 'TLS 1.2 has been enabled. You must restart the Windows Server for the changes to take affect.' -ForegroundColor Cyan
```